# What's the issue on my repository function?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-4.2, symfony-4.3

I get the following error when i try to use this in my controller

> Return value of
>   App\Repository\AccountRepository::findOneByAccountCode() must be an
>   instance of App\Repository\Bank or null, instance of
>   App\Entity\Account returned

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @param string $accountCode
 * @return Response
 * @throws EntityNotFoundException
 */
public function somefunction(Request $request, string $accountCode)
{
    /** @var BankRepository $acRepository */
    $acRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Account::class);
    $bank = $acRepository->findOneByAccountCode($accountCode);        
}
```

Repository Code

```
public function findOneByAccountCode(string $accountCode): ?Bank
{
    try {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->innerJoin('a.bank', 'b')
            ->where('a.code = :code')
            ->setParameter('code', $accountCode)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
    }catch (NonUniqueResultException $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect a bank when finding an account?

Comment: Your account repository methods are going to want to return an instance of Account by default. You'd need to use select or move the method to the bank repository

Comment: i need to get the bank.name, so you suggest i move this to my BankRepository and then i will get this 
>must be an instance of App\Repository\Account

Comment: MylesK thanks for the answer you got it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just changed the code to my AccountRepository and added array as a return type

```
function findOneByAccountCode(string $accountCode): ?array{
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->innerJoin('a.bank', 'b')
            ->where('a.code = :code')
            ->setParameter('code', $accountCode)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResults();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have just to change return type of

```
public function findOneByAccountCode(string $accountCode): ?Bank
{
    try {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->innerJoin('a.bank', 'b')
            ->where('a.code = :code')
            ->setParameter('code', $accountCode)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
    } catch (NonUniqueResultException $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

from

```
: ?Bank
```

to

```
: ?Account



public function findOneByAccountCode(string $accountCode): ?Account
{
    try {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->innerJoin('a.bank', 'b')
            ->where('a.code = :code')
            ->setParameter('code', $accountCode)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
    } catch (NonUniqueResultException $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```